# Is there a cleaner way of writing these lines of jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a cleaner way of writing these lines?

```
    $("input:text").each(function() {
     if ($(this).val() !== "")
        $(this).show().prev().addClass('highlighted').parent().parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
    });
```

EDIT: Some extra background info...

This is about a survey where the answers are saved, when going to the next question. On this particular question, the visitor can check checkboxes. However, the last 2 options are input fields. For both these input fields I made fake checkboxes and used jQuery to make those checkboxes look functional.

When you want to navigate back to this question, the regular checkboxes that you checked will still be checked, but the fake ones are not. Also the input fields are hidden, even if they have a value.

I need the jQuery above to make sure that the fake checkboxes are checked when the input field has a value. The 'highlighted' class is for extra visual confirmation that you have that answer checked.

Now here is the html. I have very little control of this markup.

```
<input class="fake-check" type="checkbox">
<div class="question-open-question">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-situations-other1">
        <label for="edit-situations-other1" class="highlighted">Ik wil: </label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-situations-other1" name="situations[other1]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now don't get me wrong. The jQuery above works. I just would like to know a cleaner way of writing this.

So, when an input field has a value, I want 3 things:
- To show that input field
- To add a class to the label
- To check the checkbox

Comment: A HTML snippet for the target elements would help.

Comment: You can insert line breaks. But you should never use `.parent().parent()`. Usually `closest` helps making your code more maintanable.

Comment: The `parent().parent().prev()` in your 3 line example is different from the one line because in the 3 line you're starting from `this` and in the one line you're starting from `$(this).prev()`.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Cleanest way? Use IDs.

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. It is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For your second version to work, you have to save `$(this).prev()` and put braces around the `if` since  you want to execute multiple statements

```
 $("input:text").each(function() {
     if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        $(this).show();
        var prev =  $(this).prev();
        prev.addClass('highlighted');
        prev.parent().parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
    }
 });
```

Note that using `prev()` and `parent()` is a brittle way because most changes to the DOM will break your JavaScript. You should mark the elements you are trying to reach with classnames and use `closest()` and `find()`

Comment: I'll try this out on monday. Instead of .parent().parent() I'll try and use .closest() like @dystroy mentioned

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to wrap everything in a container div, and then work with that rather than jumping up and down the DOM:

```
<div class="my-section">
  ...
  <span class="to-highlight">...</span>
  <input class="my-text">
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox">
</div>
```

Then your JS:

```
$(".my-section").each(function () {
    if ($(".my-text", this).val() !== "") {
        $(".my-text", this).show();
        $(".to-highlight", this).addClass("highlighted");
        $(".my-checkbox", this).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

This way your code is very well contained within one element. It is much less likely to break with HTML structure changes, and won't interfere with elements outside of its scope. I generally recommend avoiding functions that are tightly coupled with the HTML structure such as `parent()` and `prev()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have very little control over the html markup, so I can't wrap it all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:text").each(function() {
  var $t=$(this);
  if ($t.val() !== "") {
    $t.show().prev().addClass('highlighted').end().parent().parent().prev().prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Use `.end()` to go back to your previous selector (in this case `$(this)` instead of `$(this).prev()`).

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid the really long line.

Comment: Technically speaking, if `.prev()` return something, `.prev().parent()` and `$(this).parent()` is the same.

Comment: This code doesn't have `.prev().parent()`.  This was taken from the  "working as three lines" code.  Which unfortunately is not the same as the "not working as one line" code.

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned, I'd like a cleaner way of doing this.